# Invariant Concentration of Ideal Gas Mixture with Altitude

Tags: thermodynamics, atmospheric-science, ideal-gas, chemical-potential

Consider the following scenario, We have two gasses, $A$ and $B$, both approximately ideal mixed together in a gravitational field of constant magnitude $g$. Let them have masses per particle of $m_a$ and $m_b$ respectively. At elevation $z = 0$, the concetration $\frac{N_a}{N_b+N_a} = c_0$, and the total pressure is $P_0$. We wish to find the concentration of the two gasses in the mixture at arbitrary elevation $z$.

The following is my *very problematic* analysis. Let's begin with pressures. Because they are both ideal gasses, they will both individually satisfy the barometric equation

\begin{equation}\frac{\partial P}{\partial z} = -\rho g\end{equation}
or in this particular case, the two equations
\begin{equation} \frac{\partial P}{\partial z} = \frac{-Pmgz}{kT}\end{equation}
Which leads to the obvious solutions
\begin{equation}
P_a(z) = P_{a0}e^{-m_agz/kT}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
P_b(z) = P_{b0}e^{-m_bgz/kT}
\end{equation}

Now, let's consider concentration. The chemical potential of a species $A$ in a mixture is the pure chemical potential $\mu_A^o(P,T)$, with an additional term for the entropy of mixing. Given that the entropy of mixing is
\begin{equation}
-\Delta S_{mix}/k = N_a \ln(1/c) + N_b\ln\left(\frac{1}{1-c}\right)
\end{equation}
Given that $c$ is a function of $z$. The chemical potential should be
\begin{equation}
\mu_{mix,A} = \mu_{A}^o + kT\frac{\partial \Delta S}{\partial N_a} = \mu_A^o + kT\ln(1/c)
\end{equation}
If we now utilize the fact that gas $A$ must be in equilibrium, we have that
\begin{equation}
\mu_{A}^o(P(z),T,0) + kT\ln(1/c) + m_Agz = \mu_{A}^o(P_0,T,0) + kT\ln(1/c_0)
\end{equation}
Equivalently,
\begin{equation}
kT\ln(c/c_0) = \mu_{A}^o(P(z),T,0) - \mu_A^o(P_0,T,0) + m_agz
\end{equation}

If we now utilize that the chemical potential of an ideal gas is just $kT\ln(P) - \chi(T)$, this becomes
\begin{equation}
kT\ln(c/c_0) = kT\ln(P_a/P_{0a}) + m_agz
\end{equation}
And
\begin{equation}
c = c_0\frac{P_a(z)}{P_{0a}}e^{m_agz/kT} = c_0e^{-m_agz/kT}e^{m_agz/kT} = c_0
\end{equation}

Thus, one of two things is true. Either I've blundered somewhere and I can't find the mistake, or this is correct and I need to be given an intuition why this is possible. We clearly expect something like a logistic curve where the lighter of the two species becomes more prevalent at higher altitudes. I can derive that result without mixing, but I cannot seem to get it with the mixing factored in. As such, please relieve me of my ignorance!

Comment: Is the total volume of the mixture fixed? I.e., are the gases in a rigid container?

Comment: @BobD, no the intention is to model a non-convective atmosphere

Comment: Why do you write "If we now utilize that the chemical potential of an ideal gas is just kTln(P)−χ(T)" when the chemical potential in a gravitational field should contain a dependence on the height z? Also, I don't see where χ is defined.

Comment: @Chemomechanics Your right, I was a little untidy. What I mean is that this is a standard chemical potential at $h=0$, as you can see, I account for the potential energy difference separately, so its really just an issue of nomenclature. The $\chi(T)$ is meant to represent some function of $T$ which we will later ignore (It drops from the equations because it does not vary with height). Let it be arbitrary. (Of course, in a real atmosphere, the temperature would change, but I'm ignoring that effect.

Comment: In the equation following "If we now utilize the fact that gas A must be in equilibrium, we have that," you seem to double count the influence of gravity: you write $\mu_A^0=\mu_A^0(P(z), T,z)$ as incorporating $z$ already, but you also add the term $m_agz$. Doesn't this term already effectively appear inside $\mu_A^0$?

Comment: @Chemomechanics You're absolutely right! small typo. We still care about $P(z)$ vs. $P_0$, but you're right, it should be $\mu(P(z),T,0)$ on the LHS. I've made an edit.

Comment: How does $\mu_A^0(P(z),T,0)$ differ from $\mu_A^0(P_0,T,0)$? They are written as two distinct terms in the two equations you edited. It would seem to me that if $z$ is set to 0, then $P(z)$ becomes $P_0$, no?

Answer (score 2):

1. Your definition for the entropy of mixing has a sign error. The resulting chemical potential should be $\mu_{\text{mixture,}A}=\mu_A^\circ+kT\ln c$. That is, the chemical potential of a solute tends to be lower where it is more dilute, which promotes diffusional mixing because [matter moves to areas of lower chemical potential](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/363816/146039).
2. After writing "If we now utilize that the chemical potential of an ideal gas is just...," you conflate the total pressure $P$ with the partial pressure of A,
   $P_A$. They aren't equal or linearly proportional. It's the total pressure that brings in information about B that's needed to explain the concentration dependence on height.

Here's another approach to compare:

The chemical potential of A must satisfy

$$\frac{\partial (\mu_{\text{mixture,}A}+m_Agz)}{\partial z}=0.$$

(This corresponds to your equation setting the chemical potentials equal at different heights, now expressed more powerfully as a derivative equaling zero.)

Since $\mu_{\text{mixture,}A}=\mu_{\text{mixture,}A}(T,P,c)$, we have

$$\frac{\partial \mu_{\text{mixture,}A}}{\partial T}\frac{\partial T}{\partial z}+\frac{\partial \mu_{\text{mixture,}A}}{\partial P}\frac{\partial P}{\partial z}+\frac{\partial \mu_{\text{mixture,}A}}{\partial c}\frac{\partial c}{\partial z}+m_Ag=0,$$

where we seek $\frac{\partial c}{\partial z}$. Now,

- For height-independent temperature, $\frac{\partial T}{\partial z}=0$, so the first term disappears;
- We always have $\frac{\partial \mu_i}{\partial P}=V_i$ (or $\frac{kT}{P}$ for an ideal gas);
- $\frac{\partial P}{\partial z}=-\rho g=-\frac{m_\text{mixture}}{V}g$ (hydrostatic equilibrium, where $m_\text{mixture}=cm_A+(1-c)m_B$ is the total mass); and
- $\frac{\partial \mu_{\text{mixture,}A}}{\partial c}=\frac{kT}{c}$ (from the equation in (1)), giving

$$0-m_\text{mixture}g+\frac{kT}{c}\frac{\partial c}{\partial z}+m_Ag=0;$$

$$kT\frac{\partial \ln c}{\partial z}=m_\text{mixture}g-m_Ag;$$

$$\frac{c}{c_0}=\exp\left(\frac{(m_\text{mixture}-m_A)gz}{kT}\right),$$

Do these steps make sense?

You can get to this result from your (corrected) equation

$$\mu_{A}^\circ(P,T) + kT\ln(c) + m_Agz = \mu_{A}^\circ(P_0,T) + kT\ln(c_0)$$

as long as we integrate $\frac{\partial\mu_A^\circ}{\partial P}=\frac{kT}{P}$ to obtain $\mu_A^\circ(P)=\mu_A^\circ(P_0)+kT\ln\left(\frac{P}{P_0}\right)=\mu_A^\circ(P_0)-m_\text{mixture}gz$. This again gives $$-m_\text{mixture}gz + kT\ln\left(\frac{c}{c_0}\right) + m_Agz = 0$$ and thus

$$\frac{c}{c_0}=\exp\left(\frac{(m_\text{mixture}-m_A)gz}{kT}\right).$$

As noted in a comment, the result from this derivation strategy matches that from simply using partial pressures as a surrogate for concentrations:

$$\frac{c}{c_0}=\frac{\frac{P_{A}}{P}}{\frac{P_{A,0}}{P_0}}=\frac{P_{A}P_0}{P_{A,0}P}=\exp\left(\frac{(m_\text{mixture}-m_A)gz}{kT}\right).$$

Since we’re assuming ideal gases, this a perfectly valid solution strategy, albeit less extensible to other materials than the chemical potential approach outlined above.

Comment: This looks right to me! I withdraw my answer, it was wrong and I was just being too lazy when writing it.

Comment: A very strange way to determine the relative densities... Why not use the partial pressures $P_i = n_i kT_i/m_i$, divide $n_i/n_j$, done? This exercise has nothing to do with chemistry, but everything to do with mechanical forces, which obey the hydrostatic equation.

Comment: It's not always possible to use the partial pressure as a surrogate for concentration. (I agree that it's possible in this case, however.) It's useful to know more than one way to derive a result, especially more general ways that can be applied to different material classes.

Comment: @Chemomechanics: I agree with the sentiment that it is useful  to know more ways. But why I denoted this as strange is that usually solution follows the nature of a problem: In this case one would not think of applying entropies to the problem, as the species do not exchanges numbers, it is a purely mechanical, not chemical problem.

Comment: Be sure not to confuse the *chemical potential* with chemistry or chemical reactions. It is the partial molar Gibbs free energy. The problem focuses on equilibrium at ambient temperature and pressure; thus, we look to the Gibbs free energy as the natural potential that is minimized. Nature doesn't care whether one considers this a mechanical force-balancing problem or a chemical-potential minimization problem! In any case, your comments are probably best directed to the author of the question, as I wasn't the one who chose to incorporate the entropy of mixing.

Comment: @BooleanDesigns If this answer resolves your issue, please consider awarding the bounty that you offered to draw attention to the question.