# Do bubbles of humid air condense when bubbled up through water?

Tags: humidity, condensation

I'm working with an ultrasonic humidifier that bubbles the humid air produced through water. I'm wondering if the humid bubbles condense into the surrounding water. Does this happen?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The system will evolve toward equilibrium. Broadly, the concentrations (technically the [chemical potential](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/363816/146039)) of each component in the air bubble and surrounding water will tend to equalize.

Let's assume a bubble diameter exceeding, say, 1 µm, so that we can ignore the nuance of the [Laplace pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_pressure). Then, the internal bubble pressure can be assumed to equal atmospheric pressure.

Matter will diffuse in both directions through the bubble interface. If the water is not yet saturated in the gas components of the air, net diffusion of those components will occur from the bubble into the water.

Conversely, if the air in the bubble is not at 100% relative humidity, water will evaporate from the interface into the bubble as water vapor. (Interestingly, this is the opposite of the condensation you mention.)

Comment: Interesting! What if a bubble encounters colder water?

Comment: Condensation would occur if the conditions change such that the relative humidity in the bubble exceeds 100%.