# What does chemical potential really mean?

Tags: thermodynamics, chemical-potential

I do not completely understand the concept of chemical potential $\mu$:

It is usually defined by

$$\delta Q = T dS = dU + pdV + \mu dn$$

By adding, lets say 1 mole of mass to a gas of 10 moles ($\delta n = 1 mole$), I will have 11 moles afterwards.
But what does it mean in that context to "add" some amount of a component? Finally, it must make a clear difference if this added 1 mole is "hot" or "cold" and so $\delta Q$ must somehow depend on a $\mu$ that also depends on T: $\mu = \mu(T)$. But what T? T is the temperature of my system not of what I try to add.

Moreover, to fully describe a process of "adding something of given temperature" one does not really need a new quantity $\mu$; the final state after mixing can be described uniquely by gas laws, etc...
What is the benefit of defining a new quantity $\mu$ and what does it mean in view of my question?

Comment: I found [this paper](https://www.physics.rutgers.edu/grad/601/CM2019/EXTRA/understanding_chem_potential.pdf) to be extremely useful in understanding the basic *statistical mechanics* of what chemical potential is.

Comment: If you look at your equation, there is a change of entropy $\delta S$ at a fixed temperature $T$ implied on mid lhs. If in a system $\delta U =\delta V=0$, the $\delta n$ causes the change of entropy. This change of moles of the chemical compounds, can only happen in reality when there exists a fixed potential (chemical potential $\mu$) which determines how much dissipation "must" be produced under the circumstances around ($\delta$) equilibrium at $T$ for $\delta n$. Remind, we are in the domain of equilibrium TD. Addition of moles alone cannot change entropy at a fixed temperature.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could you please give an intuitive definition of chemical potential?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/363748/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quote below is from this excellent tutorial [Baierlein: The elusive chemical potential](https://www.physics.rutgers.edu/grad/601/CM2019/EXTRA/chemical_potential_meaning.pdf)

> Any response to the question, ‘‘What is the meaning of the
> chemical potential?,’’ is necessarily subjective. What satisfies
> one person may be wholly inadequate for another. Here
> I offer three characterizations of the chemical potential (denoted
> by $\mu$) that capture diverse aspects of its manifold nature.
>
> (1) *Tendency to diffuse*. As a function of position, the chemical
> potential measures the tendency of particles to diffuse.
>
> (2) *Rate of change*. When a reaction may occur, an extremum of some
> thermodynamic function determines equilibrium. The chemical potential
> measures the contribution (per particle and for an individual species)
> to the function’s rate of change.
>
> (3) Characteristic energy. The chemical potential provides a
> characteristic energy: $(\partial E/\partial N)_{S,V}$ , that is, the change in energy when
> one particle is added to the system at constant entropy (and constant
> volume).
>
> These three assertions need to be qualified by contextual
> conditions, as follows.
>
> (a) Statement (1) captures an essence, especially when the temperature
> $T$ is uniform. When the temperature varies spatially, diffusion is
> somewhat more complex and is discussed briefly under the rubric
> ‘‘Further comments’’ in Sec. IV.
>
> (b) Statement (2) is valid if the temperature is uniform and fixed.
> If, instead, the total energy is fixed and the temperature may vary
> from place to place, then $\mu/T$ measures the contribution. When one
> looks for conditions that describe chemical equilibrium, one may focus
> on each locality separately, and then the division by temperature is
> inconsequential.
>
> (c) The system’s ‘‘external parameters’’ are the macroscopic
> environmental parameters (such as external magnetic field or container
> volume) that appear in the energy operator or the energy eigenvalues.
> All external parameters are to be held constant when the derivative in
> statement (3) is formed. The subscript $V$ for volume illustrates
> merely the most common situation. Note that pressure does not appear
> in the eigenvalues, and so—in the present usage—pressure is not an
> external parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The chemical potential is not usually defined by the equation you gave.  The chemical potential is defined as the partial molar Gibbs free energy of a chemical species in solution (or a pure species).